# Close-vote power and question tags

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags

I did see that when the first close-vote is placed, the second and third follow quickly. And one thing those voters have in common is that they do not have a high reputation in the tag in which the question is posed.

Does this feature suggestions solve this problem?

- Adding a limitation for the reviewers to have enough reputation in the question tags.
- Or making questions unlisted to allow time for posters to articulate and improve their question.

Question [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73843638/timeline#history_067a758c-b195-418b-9523-e9bbf63fb6b6)

Comment: 1. why would you need time to articulate your question after posting? You have an enternity to articulate your question before you post it. 2. Everyone can see that the example question had severe problems before you edited it, which in itself is discouraged, to do such severe edits when you're not OP.

Comment: Now your question doesn't make sense on an entirely different level - you pose it's *a problem* but I see no backing to explain why. Nor do I think it's an inherent thing - close voting questions does not always require domain knowledge of the technology. A lot of questions are not answerable *as questions*, regardless of what technologies they are about.

Comment: FYI, users cannot vote to close a question unless they have at least 3000 reputation points. Re: _"Or making questions unlisted to allow time for posters to articulate and improve their question"_: There's a new feature in development right now called "Staging Ground" that will work somewhat like that.

Comment: Related: [Staging Ground](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/staging-ground/info) (re: *"...allow time for posters to articulate and improve their question."*)

Comment: Having "enough reputation" in a tag means that it would take a lot of time for _anyone on the site_ to ever be able to close a question in a _new tag_.

Comment: Related: Staging Ground ... Aside from the chat system, this is where the site most needs improvement; not all users have the capacity to get it right from the start, especially when high rep stackers swarm with downvotes make it much more difficult and discouraging to have the time to improve the question.

Comment: Closing a question *is temporary*. It is intended to be there until the question is improved. So it's not "difficult" to improve a closed question. It is, in fact, the intended outcome. You are *not* prevented from making edits.

Comment: In fact you are encouraged to make edits to your question when it’s closed. If you choose to delete your question or choose to do nothing that’s entirely on you. As others have said, (up and down) voting is anonymous, close voting isn’t. You don’t need a ton of reputation in a specific tag to identify bad questions

Answer (score 4):

> Does this feature suggestions solve this problem?

No, because there is no problem.

> And one thing those voters have in common is that they do not have a high reputation in the tag in which the question is posed.

Really? And where are your facts? Details to back up your claim? I believe you won't find such, because you are wrong.

Comment: yes Im wrong did'nt know closing vote unlocked at 3k rep,

Comment: I mean, many people do CV questions where they don't have high (if any) tag score. I'm not sure what use is there to prove that. It means little. They might be knowledgeable in the tag area but just haven't answered any questions. Or they can still recognise an off-topic question regardless of the tag.

Comment: @Shadow The Kid Wizard please colse this question its hammerd with dow,nvotes

Comment: I can't close it myself, but anyway "I'm getting downvotes" is not valid reason to close a question.

Comment: “please colse this question its hammerd with dow,nvotes” - No; Closing the question won’t prevent downvotes…

Answer (score 4):

> Does this feature suggestions solve this problem?

There is no problem. Domain expertise in a given tag is usually not needed to determine whether or not a question is on-topic.

If really not sure, users are expected to simply not vote. Which can happen regardless of what domain knowledge they have in a tag. I often avoid voting on questions that concern my primary expertise if I am not completely sure.

In the case when a question gets closed, yet it should not have been, it can also be reopened. Although, it is likely that an update to the question is needed to clarify it.